# "Access denied" when trying to move a directory in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch, file-transfer, robocopy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access denied, cmd move windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/338611/access-denied-cmd-move-windows-7)

I can't use this command in Windows 7 when I want to move a directory. If the destination exists, it says "Access denied".

Why does this happen? It worked in XP.

```
move /y "%1" c:\mydir\
```

I can use `robocopy`, but then it will move only the contents of the folder, not the folder completly.

```
robocopy "%1" c:\mydir /E /IS /MOVE
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: When moving files then move command works well. But when source is a folder then it fails if destination alredy exists and it has to overwrite.