# Windows Move Command: Odd 'Access Denied'

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, file-transfer, file-permissions

I am trying to move folders from D: to C: but am getting 'Access Denied'.  I have ownership and full control over every folder in question and am running as local admin in `administrator mode`.  What's odd is it only fails when I try to move between drives.

*I can create and delete files/folders in either drive*

```
C:\>move sub c-Move
        1 dir(s) moved

C:\>md d:\test
C:\>md d:\test-1
C:\>move d:\test-1 d:\test
       1 dir(s) moved
C:\>rd /q /s d:\test
C:\>
```

*I can copy between drives*

```
C:\>copy d:\test\test.txt c:\move
        1 file(s) copied
```

*But I cannot move between them*

```
C:\>move d:\test c:\c-Move
Access is denied.
```

**Why can't I move these files?**

Note (similar question): [Access denied, cmd move windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/338611/access-denied-cmd-move-windows-7), except "want to move a directory if the destination exists".

Comment: I faintly remember something about a *move* operation being different from a *copy and delete* operation under certain circumstances. I just remember it from the UNIX domain. Like here: http://insanelabs.com/linux/linux-cannot-move-folders-inter-device-move-failed-unable-to-remove-target-is-a-directory/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Move-Item will move files between drives that are supported by the same provider, but it will move directories only within the same drive.

[Microsofts documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849852.aspx) is pretty clear, I bet this is because it only alters the filesystem index and not the real location of the directory.

Comment: I hate it when the answer is that simple.  Not sure why I couldn't find that on my own, but thank you.